# Execute queries or macros in Teradata using Tibco EMS

Tags: tibco, tibco-ems, tibco-designer

Is it possible to execute queries or call macros in Teradata through TIBCO EMS?
If so, what is the process?
If not, what is the correct Tibco product to perform this action?

Answer (score 0):

TIBCO EMS is a messaging product that transports data from one point to another. To do something, you'll need to have a producer and a consumer of messages connected to it and the consumer of those messages would be able to execute queries in Teradata.

If you want to connect to Teradata and execute those queries to visualize them. In that case TIBCO Spotfire is the best suited TIBCO product for the job. You can find details on how to connect to Teradata using TIBCO Spotfire [here](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/sfire-analyst/10.0.0/doc/html/en-US/TIB_sfire-analyst_UsersGuide/connectors/tera/tera_details_on_teradata_connection.htm).

Answer (score 0):

You must connect EMS queues/topics to a listener service developed in C/Java/.NET/BusinessWorks to read incoming messages and for each messages received you can do actions to Teradata. I am not familiar with Teradata but API in Java could exist to permit you to call macros in the listener service.